# How to place a `button` view in the center at the bottom of the entire layout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

How to place a `button` view in the center at the bottom of the entire layout? In the `button` item in the xml file I used `android:layout_gravity` and `android:gravity` but I did not see any effect.

xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.meetingpointlocator_03" >  

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/introScreenTitleID"
    android:text="@string/introScreenTitle"
    android:textColor="@color/introScreenTitleColor"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="top|center"
    android:textSize="@dimen/introScreentitle">
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/introScreenContentID"
    android:textColor="@color/introScreenContentscolor"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="bottom|center"
    android:textSize="@dimen/introScreenContentFontSize">
</TextView>

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/introButtonID"
    android:text="Proceed"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="bottom|center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Do you have a vertical RelativeLayout or LinearLayout wrapping your xml or is that xml complete?

Comment: please see the updated xml

Answer (score 0):

change your button to, noting the bottom two items I added:

```
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/introButtonID"
    android:text="Proceed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/introScreenContentID" />
```

`android:gravity` is for setting where the content within your view goes. Also don't worry about the `android:layout_gravity`, you should be using layout_below for your TextViews also

Comment: but now the button is place at the very bottom left of the layout and not centered!

Comment: should i use alightLeft to center the button

Comment: then do `android:layout_gravity="center"` .. `layout_gravity` tells the parent item how to handle the child

Comment: items in RelativeLayout works best with android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.meetingpointlocator_03" >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/introScreenTitleID"
        android:text="@string/introScreenTitle"
        android:textColor="@color/introScreenTitleColor"
        android:textSize="@dimen/introScreentitle"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
    </TextView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/introScreenContentID"
            android:textColor="@color/introScreenContentscolor"
            android:text="Some Text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/introScreenContentFontSize">

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/introButtonID"
        android:text="@string/introButtonText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
</LinearLayout
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code, it will fulfill your requirement,

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/introButtonID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Proceed" />
```

AlignParentBottom will place it at the bottom and center horizontal will place in center.

Answer (score 0):

Relative layout have some properties to set view in center,in left,right and bottom also,you have to use

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

in your button like i used in your button code below:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/your_button_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="text" />
```

i hope this will help you!!